# Algorithm for finding population for a given center point and radius in US

Tags: population, demography, ruby

Here is what I have

1. The population data aggregated by zip code given by US Census.

Here is what I am doing right now:

1. Reverse geo code the center point to find the zip code of the center
   point.
2. Associate a lat-long to each zip-code(by reverse geocoding, I know
   this will be error prone).
3. Find the lat-longs(zip-codes) which are inside the circle, using
   Geokit-Rails plugin.
4. Finding the sum of the data for those zip-codes(zip-code=zipcode of the center point or distance(between lat-long of the zip code and center point) < radius) and showing.

Am I doing this right? Is there methods efficient than this to find the population? Is there any algorithm already available?

I am using geokit-rails plugin for reverse geocoding and for finding the zip-codes(with associated lat-longs) within the circle.

The problem with this setup is that the zipcodes cannot be actually represented by the lat-long,it is an area.So, I am not sure the lat-long pair given by Google Map API is actually lies in the center of the zip code or something like that. Also,for radius 0 to almost 2.4 miles radius,the population remains same with this setup. That is, even for a radius of 0.1 miles, it will show the whole population of the zip code.I am looking for a way to approximate this.

I have asked [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7924186/algorithm-for-finding-population-for-a-given-center-point-and-radius-in-us) in SO. Please have a look at this question also.

Comment: Yopu haven't actually said what you are trying to achieve - this is quite important. You already have population by zip code, what is it you want?

Comment: @Stev_k..I want a way to approximate the transition from 0 miles to the boundary of the first zip code, likewise (now it will be the population for the zip code which the point it belongs, even if the radius selected is 0 or 0.2 or 0.4 or 1 or 2 miles etc.)..just rough approximation will be enough..

Comment: Maybe I just haven't had enough coffee yet, but I'm having a hard time visualizing what you're talking about.  A simple graphic illustration would be most helpful.

Comment: I'm with other commentors - Not sure what you are trying to get but it seems that doing a radius to find crossing population would not be very accurate. i.e. If you cross by just .00001 percent of the poly you get 100% of the population.

Comment: Why not use Census 2010 Block TIGER data or 5-yr ACS data? Or Landscan?

Comment: @BradNesom..by my algorithm now, the scenario is like this - if the centroid of the zip code comes inside the circle, the 100% of the population of the zip code will be included.

Comment: @MLowry..I checked the Census 2010 Block TIGER data but was not able to understand what each column represent. Can you help me a bit there, as I am totally new to this?

Answer (score 2):

OK, so you have points representing the centroids of the zip codes, but not the full boundaries of the zip codes themselves, right?

I'm not sure how you would go about this in Ruby, and I think this may be more processing than you want to do, but a common way to do this in GIS software would be Voroni Polygons (http://www.georeference.org/doc/transform_voronoi_operators.htm). A possible methodology would be to build a polygon layer from all the points - which only has to be done once, then test which area each point is in. I'm still not 100% certain about what your input and output data are though, so I'm unsure whether this method would be more efficient.

It's a bit more difficult to find open source implementations for Voroni methodologies, but apparently there is a plugin for QGIS (Python) http://michaelminn.com/linux/mmqgis/

Comment: thanks for your response..so after building approximate polygon layer from the points, what should be the next step? How will I store the polygon boundary points? How to find how much of a single polygon is inside the circle ? I am very new to this. Please bear with me.

Comment: I am making a lot of assumptions here because the general agreement here is that you still haven't told us exactly what you want. But, assuming what you need is a polygon layer representing zip code boundaries, I would a) create voroni areas in a GIS b) load these into a PostGIS / Spatialite database. Assuming what you then want to work out the population around a certain point I would use Mersey Vikings instructions below. PHP / Python queries on the database might be more suitable than pure Ruby and while this is very doable there may be a few bumps along the way ...

Comment: Just found this ruby geolibrary http://www.daniel-azuma.com/blog/archives/28 although it doesn't appear to do some of the things you need, namely intersections, unions, or differences

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, it is a little unclear, but if I understand you correctly, you have polygon data with a population count attribute. You want to specify a centre and radius of a circle to find the approximate population under that circle.

If that's the case, then the broad steps I'd use are:

1. Calculate the population density of each polygon by dividing its population attribute by its area.
2. Create a circle polygon representing your area of interest.
3. Intersect a polygon with your circle.
4. Find the area of each intersection and multiply it by the population density for that polygon.
5. Rinse and repeat from step 3 for each polygon that is intersected by your circle.
6. Sum up the results to get the approximate total population.

If, as @Stev_k says, you don't have the polygon dataset, then you'll have to find a way of deriving the polygons from the data you have.

Comment: How will I find the area shared between the zip code polygon and the circle? Where will I get the data for finding the polygon boundaries for each zip code? Sorry, if I sound like a noob but that is what I am I guess :(

Answer (score 0):

Would something like David Martin's [population surface software](http://www.public.geog.soton.ac.uk/users/martind/davehome/popmod.htm) be what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

To get an accurate population count, you should probably look into [Apportionment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apportionment) techniques, like that described [here](https://www.socialtext.net/sonoran/apportionment_of_block_group_variables_to_quarter_sections), [here](http://www.ij-healthgeographics.com/content/8/1/33), [here](http://www.biomedcentral.com/content/pdf/1476-072X-8-33.pdf), and [here](http://www.andrew.cmu.edu/course/95-708/GISPowerPointLectures_files/slide0042.htm) (Lecture 9, starting on slide 40).

Even if you choose not to use apportionment, if you at least use the [2010 Census Block](http://www.census.gov/geo/www/tiger/tgrshp2010/rdo.html) centroids, you should be able to get a much better estimate of custom polygon population counts.