# How to get the "Join attributes by location" features on a QGIS Mac version

Tags: spatial-join, qgis-3, mac

I am using QGIS 3.2.0Bonn on a macOS High Sierra (10.15).

I am trying to do a simple procedure on QGIS for Mac, following a tutorial which was built for Windows (so it seems).

What I want to do is to *perform spatial joins*, following this very awesome [tutorial](https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/performing_spatial_joins.html) page.

The problem is that the option "Take summary of intersecting features" is not available at the "`Vector -> Data Mangement Tools -> Join attributes by location`" dialog box on my QGIS version. This is how the option window looks like to me:
[image]

I have seen similar question [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/41956/summing-attributes-intersected-by-under-a-radius). But both answers to this question referred to using the feature but did not explain how to "get it" or where to find it on QGIS for Mac.

Is there a solution to this feature on QGIS for Mac?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Screenshots would certainly help. Since QGIS 3 includes many improvements and changes, any tutorial written for 2.x versions will be more or less off.

That said, there should be a **Join Attributes by location (summary)** tool in the Processing toolbox of QGIS 3.2:

[image]

Not the documentation stating that

> "The algorithm calculates a statistical summary for the values from
>   matching features in the second layer (e.g. maximum value, mean value,
>   etc)."