# How to join maximum values from a polygons layer to other gridded polygons layer in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, spatial-join, vector-grid

I have two overlapping SHPs. One is with two noncontinous polygons - values 0 is blue and 1 is green. Now I have 9 meters grid for the same area, but I need to "fill" the grid with values from previsous shapefile - not by averaged, but by maximum value (it means when one small polygon with value 1 is underlaying the grid, then the whole grid cell has new value 1).  Below is the picture. I'm afraid all this spatial join tools does it only by averaged values.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the answer here:  [How to get the "Join attributes by location" features on a QGIS Mac version](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/288026/how-to-get-the-join-attributes-by-location-features-on-a-qgis-mac-version)    . Use the **Join by Location (Summary)** tool . you can find it in the Processing Toolbox.

Answer (score 0):

First create a virtual field (using Field Calculator), use the tools in there to populate the virtual field with "Max(##)" values. 
The do a spatial join attributes.